Jquery datepicker position issue when scrolling
jquery ui-datepicker calendar control position not sticking to the input div while scrolling the page in a small size screen
jquery ui-datepicker should stick relative the input div even on scrolling the page  in a small size screen

Add your code please.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
